# Org-mode command to hide-branches

Tags: org-mode

I use quite a lot the useful command `show-branches` and I couldn't find the analogue command to hide all the branches under a certain Item. In other words my aim is to fold only a subtree and its parent. How to do this?

Comment: What exactly would this analogue do? Try `C-h f hide-` then `TAB` to see what functions are available.

Comment: Have you tried `org-cycle` (`TAB`) and `org-shifttab` (shift and `TAB` together)? These will cycle back and forth between different levels of tree vicibility.

Comment: Yes! Everything gets folded! I would like to fold only a subtree and its parent.

Comment: `(defun hide-subtree-and-parent ()
      (interactive)
      (outline-up-heading 1)
      (hide-subtree))` then bind it to some key.

Comment: Thank you this worked like a charm! Can you answer the  question? :)

Comment: Done. Be sure to use @ markers in your comments for people to be notified.  Also, could you edit your question according to the clarifications you provided in the comments?  That way the question will be more usefull to other people in the future.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is to fold a subtree and its parent.  Doing `C-h f hide-` `TAB` shows there's apparently nothing doing exactly that, but there's a `hide-subtree` command:

> (hide-subtree)
>
> Hide everything after this heading at deeper levels.

So you could go up one heading (move to the parent) and then `hide-subtree`.  Let's define a (very simple) command to do that:

```el
(defun hide-subtree-and-parent ()
  (interactive)
  (outline-up-heading 1)
  (hide-subtree))
```

You can then bind this command to a key (here `C-c h`) if you use it very often.

```el
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 
   (lambda () (define-key org-mode-map "\C-ch" 'hide-subtree-and-parent)))
```

Comment: This does not implement the right behaviour: if the current headline has a shown sister headline, that one is hidden too (but shouldn't).